# Looking to code a bot to go to a website and do stuff for me but I keep getting Chrome not reachable errors

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've tried downloading chromedriver and setting a manual path there instead of doing, driver = webdriver.Chrome() I just keep getting the same errors.

Heres the code so far

from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wd.implicitly_wait(10)

wd.get('https://www.newegg.com/msi-geforce-rtx-3090-rtx-3090-ventus-3x-24g-oc/p/N82E16814137596?Item=N82E16814137596&cm_sp=SH-*--*-8-*--*-14-137-596-*-rtx+3060-*-rtx+3060-_-1')

and yes im trying to make a bot to get myself a gpu because ive tried over 2 years now plus waiting in lines in the middle of the night so dont judge me. The url is also just a place holder for now
[1] This is the error code I get
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLIbn.png

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a little confusing. Let me unfold it line-by-line:

line 1: `driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')`
You are assigning Chrome driver (with executable_path) to an instance called `driver`

line 2: `driver = webdriver.Chrome()`
I am not sure why you are using this line, but I for now would assume that you are trying this line by commenting out the first one, in which case, your chromedriver path needs to be in Environment Variables path (if its Windows). Not sure about Mac or Linux though

line 3: `wd.implicitly_wait(10)` Here is where the code gets murkier. You assigned chromedriver instance to `driver`', but instead of using it, you are trying to use `wd`, to which no driver instance nothing is assigned.

Change these lines like this:

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

driver.get('https://www.newegg.com/msi-geforce-rtx-3090-rtx-3090-ventus-3x-24g-oc/p/N82E16814137596?Item=N82E16814137596&cm_sp=SH----8----14-137-596--rtx+3060--rtx+3060-_-1')
```

Comment: It worked, thank you so much! I had kind of a brain fart and now it seemed like such a simple fix for me. Appreciate it !